# PlatformNotSupportedException while using System.Data.SqlClient in Unity3D

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

So I have been developing a Unity application for industrial purposes. I am looking to connect it directly to my SQL Server Database. I am not worried about security or anything otherwise I would use a webservice, so direct to the DB makes the most sense for deployment time here.

I have several other DLLs loaded into Unity as external plugins such as `Newtonsoft.Json`, `NModbus` and `Dapper`, so I know that process works. However, when I add `System.Data.SqlClient`, I get the following error:

> PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) (at <96d33b42cd1045a395dc2ad162924ac9>:0)

The stack trace for this error is the first instance of a call to the library with a constructor call here.

```
   using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            Dictionary<string, AppSetting> dataset = new Dictionary<string, AppSetting>();

            List<AppSetting> values = connection.Query<AppSetting>($"dbo.spGetAllAppSetting").AsList();

            foreach (AppSetting v in values)
                dataset.Add(v.Name, v);

            return dataset;
        }
```

The process I used was to get the .dll was to go to Nuget.org, and download `System.Data.SqlClient v4.8.3`. I then changed the extension of .nupkg to .zip, and extracted it. I then went into the `lib/netstandard-2.0/` folder to access the .dll. I have checked my Unity settings and the API compatibility is set to `.NET Standard 2.0`.

I then just add the .dll to the Assets/Plugins folder I made in my Unity Project. The DLL loads into the project and is recognized during coding. The error above only shows up whenever a method from the library is used.

Since then I have tried different versions as well as using the .NET Framework 4.6 versions available as well as the same process with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` with even more errors being found with those routes.

Any ideas on how to properly use `System.Data.SqlClient` in Unity would be much appreciated. Worst case I will bite the bullet and make a web service. Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you developing for? the error is clear whatever you picked is not supported

Comment: @BugFinder I am developing for PC. Is there somewhere that I have to specify that, that isn't just the build menu when publishing?

Comment: i dont have unity on this laptop but as long as the titlebar does indeed say windows, id be also expecting it to work as long as you used the one from the unity folder. However i was expecting you to say webgl, or something else.. in which case i wouldnt have been surprised

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah it says PC in the window titlebar as well as made sure my build settings had it selected. Yeah this is what has me stumped for sure. I will try updating my unity editor but I am doubtful that is the issue

Comment: and you got the dll from the unity folders not a normal dotnet one right?

Comment: @BugFinder I downloaded it right from nuget using the process I mentioned in the question. Is that not the correct way. Looking in C:/Program Files/Unity/ there are like 5 different System.Data.SqlClient.dll files. Is it supposed to be one of those?

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft.Data.SqlClientt instead? System.Data.SqlClient is... fussy

Comment: there is an sqllient provided by unity in their folders, i would suggest using that one

Answer (score 0):

[Missing .dll's for connecting C# to SQL Server in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087247/missing-dlls-for-connecting-c-sharp-to-sql-server-in-unity)

1. You are missing some references it seems. You should be adding the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package via NuGet, that will take care of dependencies
2. Well, after trying different solutions regarding adding the .dll's, I found that the project settings were not right. So, to help anyone that might run into the same problem: My solution was to go to the project settings -> player -> "Configuration" header and make sure that the "Api Compatibility Level" is on .NET 4.X and NOT on .NET 2.X