# Missing .dll's for connecting C# to SQL Server in Unity

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server (on some Azure server) through C# within Unity. However, I keep running into different issues as to the point that I have no clue on how to resolve them, and where the online tutorials I found stop with explaining on how their solutions works.

I have this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data;

public class DataBaseConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
    // after the SQL query is executed, we will have a filled users array
    List<float> SensorValue = new List<float>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        SensorValue = ConnectToDB();
    }

    // function to connect to the db and retrieve the data
    List<float> ConnectToDB()
    {
        List<float> SensorValue = new List<float>();
        // Build connection string
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "xxx";
        builder.UserID = "xxx";
        builder.Password = "xxx";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "xxx";

        try
        {
            // connect to the database
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                // if open then the connection is established
                connection.Open();
                Debug.Log("connection established");
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }

        return SensorValue;
    }
}
```

However, I can't even start to create the connection. First of all, the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace was missing, so I have added that in the "Assets" folder of the Unity project. Upon trying to debug then, I get a message:

> Error: Could not load signature of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider:.ctor due to: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae' or one of its dependencies. assembly:Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae type: member:(null) signature:

In order to address that issue, I added the Microsoft.Identity.Client dll to the asset folder, but this came on up with 10+ other .dll's that couldn't be found, which seem very unlogical in my humble opinion. Is there anything that I can do in order to resolve this issue?

NB: in various tutorials I found that they are using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, but when using this namespace even the reference to the namespace (such as `SqlConnection`) couldn't be found and I got the error message that the namespace was missing... I googled a bit around and found that [Microsoft decided to replace the `System.Data.SqlClient` with a new Microsoft version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/). So that doesn't seem to resolve it..

Comment: You are missing some references it seems. You should be adding the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package via NuGet, that will take care of dependencies

Comment: @Charlieface: I did try that, but unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue..

Comment: Might be an issue with DLL versions. Try removing all relevant packages, then readding the main package again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying different solutions regarding adding the .dll's, I found that the project settings were not right. So, to help anyone that might run into the same problem: My solution was to go to the project settings -> player -> "Configuration" header and make sure that the "Api Compatibility Level" is on .NET 4.X and NOT on .NET 2.X